# What app is this? Looks to be related to Google Navigation?

Tags: applications, 7.1-nougat

My wife and I got ourselves a couple of Pixel XL phones last week.
I noticed an icon on her phone that wasn't in mine named 'Driving' [and it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsJGe.png). Opening the app takes me straight to Google Navigation - [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N926.jpg).

[image: icon] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>icon and screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

So what app is this? It looks to be a legit Google app but poking around in the Play Store didn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a quick access widget, these were implemented in android 7.1 and a lot of google apps have them. just long press a google app in the Pixel Launcher or Google Now Launcher.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Google Maps widget to go straight into the driving activity. You can see it when adding widgets to the home screen.